# index multiple characters in a list

Tags: python, indexing

I'm trying to index multiple characters, for example, if the list is:

```
N00000035,Z,X,Y
```

I want to index the set of characters before the first comma:

```
N00000035
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
with open(filename+".txt", 'r') as f:
        for item in f:
            print(item[1,8])
```

But It doesn't seem to work when I print out "item[1,8]" -- this bit of code is within a larger try/except block and it seems to go straight to except block when I execute the code I have above, which tells me something about it is invalid.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It is not really clear what you mean by `index` here?

Comment: If fetching the first string before the `comma` is what you want,it can be done fairly easily with a `split`. Pranav's answer should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` on the string. Delimiter is a comma.

```
>>> str = "N00000035,Z,X,Y"
>>> str.split(',')[0]
'N00000035'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all put the data in a string and then split the string as below:

```
>>> st = "N00000035,Z,X,Y"
>>> splited = st.split(",")
>>> splited
['N00000035', 'Z', 'X', 'Y']
```

Then you can access the letters as below:

```
>>> for i in splited[0]:
    print i


N
0
0
0
0
0
0
3
5
```

You can also use indexing as below:

```
>>> splited[0][0]
'N'
>>> splited[0][1]
'0'
>>> splited[0][2]
'0'
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, `item[1, 8]` isn't the correct syntax to get the first 8 characters. The correct syntax is `item[1:8]`, or to fix those numbers to get everything before the first comma, `item[0:9]` or just `item[:9]`:

```
>>> item[:9]
'N00000035'
```

If your columns are fixed width, this approach will work fine, but otherwise you should consider the other answers and use `item.split(',')[0]` instead, which is much more flexible:

```
>>> item.split(',')[0]
'N00000035'
```